# Discord bot how would i make the bot check for server ownership

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make commands that are exclusive to the guild's owner, how would i check that? The closest of what i want is the `ADMINISTRATOR` permission but not owner

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Guild#owner`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerID), like this:

```js
msg.member.id === msg.guild.ownerID // Returns true if the message was sent by the guild owner.
```

Comment: If you're only comparing the id, you should use [`Guild.ownerID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerID)

Comment: @Lioness100 Thanks! I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

D Pardal's answer is 100% correct.
I'm not sure how familiar with the docs you are, but it could be helpful to start getting a feel for how to find things like that from the Discord.js docs. It, at least for me, helps to gain an understanding of just what every object/class they provide does. If you already know this, and just had a bit of a mental block, just ignore this & have a nice day. Otherwise, I'm waiting on a question of my own, so I figured I'd help out with what I know. I invite you to step through the docs at Discord.js.org with me as I explain this to see exactly what I'm talking about. Until recently, I found the Discord.js.org docs crazily complicated and un-understandable, so I'm hoping I can make it a little easier for you, and anyone else down the line, who could benefit from them.

---

Something to glean from this is that data about members in a guild can be found in the Guild object representing the guild. How do we find that?

Well, the only place we have to start is (probably, assuming your bot just takes in messages and executes commands based on them) the message we take in, we'll call it message. Going to the Discord.JS docs, scrolling  through the Classes on the side, eventually we see that there is, in fact, a [Message class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message)!

Now we can look and see what data ships with it, which is a wide variety of things that may be useful to you down the road. If we look close enough, the Message obj does have a property that sounds like what we're looking for, [Message.Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild)! The docs say that property is of of type Guild, & clicking the hyperlink, it takes us to the class definition for a Guild.

According to the [definition](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild), a Guild object represents a Guild on discord, so with any luck, we can get some information about things *in* said guild. Knowing that we're looking for a specific member in the guild, we might be tempted to look into the Guild#members property- and while that could be useful down the line, it doesn't get us
particulaly close to knowing who the owner is, just who all the members are.

Finally, if we scroll a bit further, we see that the Guild Class has a property called [Owner](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=owner), AND ownerID! Depending on what we want, either could be useful. Owner is a GuildMember object, a representation of a user that contains a lot of details (just like how a Guild object is a representation of a guild with lots of info about it). However, if we just need the ID for something like, say, checking the ID of the command sender to the ID of the owner, we can just get the ID property of the owner object.

In an expanded form you could visualize that like such

```
const guild = message.guild
const ownerID = guild.ownerID
```

Or condensed like

```
const ownerID = message.guild.ownerID
```

If there's anything I can clarify further let me know! I know I couldn't figure out the docs for the longest time, so I hope this helped at least somewhat.